# C++ strings, the string cant contain the plus sign

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a more advanced calculator where you enter a piece of algebra.
I have this problem, the string that contains what you inputted doesn't test positive for '+' even when it does.

This is the code that tests the string

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    if(pos == 0 && line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9' || line[i] == '.')
    {           
        p1[p1p] = line[i]; // setting the number to the current character
        p1p++; // position of the first number  
    }
    if(line[i] == '+')
    {
    pos++; 
    operation = 1;
    cout << "add" << endl;
    }
}
```

It will never out put + unless there is no space between the last character of the number and the + symbol

e.g. '100+10' would test positive for '+'
but  '100 + 10' wouldn't.

Thanks -Hugh

Comment: how do you input or get the length of the string?

Comment: string line;
cin >> line;
the string has a .length() function.

Comment: There is your problem :-)

Comment: `cin >> line` will stop at the first space.

Comment: Also be careful with that if, `if(pos == 0 && line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9' || line[i] == '.')`. Add parentheses.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea! Yeah, I will clean that up!

Comment: (I'm tempted to vote to close this too.)  If you initialise pos to 0 before the loop, and operator to something other than 1, then you will clearly see them changed (and "add\n") if `'+'` appears anywhere in `line`.  If that's not happening, then line doesn't contain the text you think it should.  More generally, you're going to struggle to write expression evaluation code - you'd be better off finding one already written, or if you're doing this to teach yourself - could consider using the boost spirit library to express tokens and grammar at a higher level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is correct you input the data with `std::cin`. which is why it does not read characters after the first white space.

use `getline()` function instead.

Comment: ...and then? Use `line.find("+") != std::string::npos`?

Comment: @WaleedKhan then write your own parser for your calculator? :-) Its obviously not _that_ simple to write a calculator. Let alone "advanced" calculator

Comment: Also, just to be a little more accurate, the whitespace in the grammar is redundant. The OP must find a way to skip whitespaces or split the string based on whitespace

Comment: @WaleedKhan now, why your `line.find("+")` will fail is because what if I input an expression like so: (+20-30) should I be doing subtraction or addition? :-)

Comment: I can only accept an awnser in 3 minutes, but this worked perfectly. There should be better standard cin functions!

Comment: @TheHugh100, yes iostream library is pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `operator>>` which naturally reads (optionally) space separated values.

```
int val;
while(std::cin >> val)
{
    // We have a value (an integer)

    char c;
    if (std::cin >> c)
    {
        // we have read the next non space character
        switch(c)
        {
            case '+': std::cout << "Adding: " << val << "\n";break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this is that for what I want to do, this would limit me in the future.

Comment: @TheHugh100: In what way. This is the standard way of reading data. From streams strings or anything streamy like (user input/files/sockets etc).